# create a .msi file in visual studio using Installshield

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, installshield

I am creating a setup project of my application and I am expecting a .msi file from my application after build it, so for that I used Installshield Limited Edition.

### Purpose of my Application

The application will track user timings on system lock unlock and it will do some extra task by interacting user outlook mails. So I have created a web service which has the built in functionality for tracking system lock unlock functionality but it's unable to interact user outlook mail.

Then I found something that "Task Scheduler: which has the same functionality(Track Lock and Unlock), so what I did I have created a .exe file in my project which will run when system unlock from Task Scheduler. For this I need to have that exe file somewhere in my system so I have added my exe file and its config file to my setup project and I have coded inside that when my application setup will run it will schedule the task automatically.

Now when I am building my setup as Single Image I am getting a SetUp file which is solving my purpose but I need a .msi file of my project which will target the same purpose even I have tried for other build types it's giving other files as well as .msi file which is not working.

I google about it I found Something that I need to "Set Compression on the build tab to yes and .... but I couldn't found anything like this.

Does it possible in Limited Edition if Yes then please suggest me.

Comment: Dont. Try WIX. Free extension, full featured and - well - from microsoft / under microsoft guidance. What they use.

Comment: http://wixtoolset.org/

Comment: I agree that WiX is better than InstallShield Limited Edition (and probably even InstallShield professional editions). But it does take some time to learn how to use it. And it's not clear to me from your question exactly what your problem is.